# What is 上寿し and how is it pronounced?

Tags: readings, culture

I encountered it here

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/local/michinoku/20230418-OYT8T50006/

「上寿し【??】」は８００【はっぴゃく】円【えん】、「人生相談【じんせいそうだん】」はゼロ円【えん】

*"---" is 800 yen, and "life counseling" costs zero yen.*

I also found it here...
[https://hanazen-michinobechuou.eeat.jp/product/上寿し2人盛〜5人盛-※表示価格は２人盛です/](https://hanazen-michinobechuou.eeat.jp/product/%E4%B8%8A%E5%AF%BF%E3%81%972%E4%BA%BA%E7%9B%9B%E3%80%9C5%E4%BA%BA%E7%9B%9B-%E2%80%BB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E4%BE%A1%E6%A0%BC%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%92%E4%BA%BA%E7%9B%9B%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/)

...but I have not found a dictionary entry for it. What is it, and how is it pronounced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is another way to write 上寿司 (high-grade sushi), pronounced じょうずし or less commonly じょうすし. Grades can be two (並寿司, 上寿司) or three (並寿司, 上寿司, 特上寿司). Some shops may have the 松, 竹, and 梅 grades instead.

In the picture, the next item is 並寿し, which is lower grade and thus less expensive at 700 yen. Similarly, this is 並寿司 written differently.